# Writing iPhone filesystem in background mode

Tags: iphone, file, background, mode

I am writing an app that logs GPS locations to a file on the iPhone and has to continue updating the locations in background mode. Now I am wondering what is the best way of doing this. Is it good practice to open the file and keep it open when my app goes in to background mode or should I close it and re-open it whenever the app needs to write a new location?

Comment: So your choices are "kill the battery" or "plays well with others"? ... hmmm, hard call

Comment: Does it kill the battery when I have an open file handle? I don't understand the "plays well with others" part, could you explain what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Why keeping open/re-opening the file?

You can let it "write" the location data to an `NSMutableArray` and write it to a file before your App gets killed or if the user manually saves it by pressing a button.

As drachenstern already mentioned, it will suck the battery dry to have location services on all the time...might lead to a bad UX

Comment: If I only register for significant location changes it shouldn't be too hard on the battery (according to the programming guide). I can keep the locations in an NSMutableArray for a while but I will have to flush them to file every now and then to free up memory and not loose all my data when the battery goes empty.